# LibreOffice Calc, how to filter rows based on interval

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I would like to filter a spreadsheet on LibreOffice 3.4.4 Calc, based on values of a second spreadsheet column. How can I do that ?

I would like intersection and, if possible, complement filters. So the result would be only cells that are in the other spreadsheet, or cells in the first that are *not* in the other.

Comment: So I figured it out doing Advanced filtering, and then I found a terrible issue here: http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=44999 (which limits size of filtering criteria).